# node express: mock authorize function in app.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm practicing with simple .get methods in node/express. I'm following an example of a book, but I have no session variable and i have no templates; so i've commented that lines and i've replaced them with a simple .send method, and i've replaced with a simple hardcode variable: authorized.

I'm getting the error:  `ReferenceError: res is not defined`

The problem is that I have no res variable, because the control pass first on authorize function.

```
function authorize(req, res, next){
    authorized = true;
    // if(req.session.authorized) return next();
    if(authorized) return next();
    res.send('not-authorized');
}
app.get('/secret', authorize, function(){
    // res.render('secret');
    res.send('secret');
});
app.get('/sub-rosa', authorize, function(){
    // res.render('sub-rosa');
    res.send('sub-rosa');
});
```

Comment: You probably need `function(req, res) {` instead of `function() {` in both cases.

Comment: thanks it's works, but how many function(req, res) can i add after the path ?  i did not find the documentation for app.get, it's  express or node syntax  ?

Comment: @stackdave You can add any number of them. `app.get('/my/path', handler1, handler2, handlerArray, function(req,res,next){next()}, function(req,res){})`. Just make sure that all handlers have 3 parameters - `(req,res,next)`, except for the last one, which doesn't need `next`.

Comment: @stackdave you can read more about it in the official documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html , the 'Route handlers` part.

Comment: thanks @hlfrmn for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to comments, the solution is:

```
function authorize(req, res, next){
    authorized = true;
    // if(req.session.authorized) return next();
    if(authorized) return next();
    res.send('not-authorized');
}
app.get('/secret', authorize, function( req, res ){
    // res.render('secret');
    res.send('secret');
});
app.get('/sub-rosa', authorize, function( req, res ){
    // res.render('sub-rosa');
    res.send('sub-rosa');
});
```